# Novel: Girl starts seeing ghosts after car accident

Tags: story-identification, ghost

So I read this back in high school and now I have book amnesia and can’t remember it! It was about a girl who suddenly started seeing ghosts after she was in a car accident that killed her brother and his girlfriend.

Comment: Hey! This is a great start, but any tiny, inconsequential details you remember could help. What language was the book in? When were you in high school? Do you remember what the cover looked like?

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [Dark Souls](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10048876-dark-souls) by Paula Morris? It was published in 2011.

[image: Dark Souls]

Googling suggests this is a common trope, but *Dark Souls* seems to match quite well. The girl is *Miranda*, her brother is *Rob* and the girlfriend is *Jenna*. If this is the book it should be easy to remember as it's set in the city of York in the UK.

Miranda realises she can see ghosts immediately after the crash when she sees Jenna's ghost walking away:

> Miranda opened her mouth to cry out: She could still see the Jenna in the car, buckled and squashed and bloodied. But here was this other Jenna walking toward her, smiling. She drifted her fingers across Miranda’s scalp, brushing Miranda’s hair back from her stinging forehead. Jenna’s touch was gentle, but it felt like the iciest winter wind.
>
> Jenna took another few steps into the field and disappeared, dissolving into the darkness. Miranda called out her name. She staggered to her feet, the jacket falling off her shoulders, calling Jenna’s name over and over again. The corn rustled back at her, keeping its secrets. One of the deputies got her to sit down again, and to drink some water. Miranda heard them saying that it would be better if she sat with her back to the car so she wouldn’t have to stare at her friend’s body trapped there in the front seat.
>
> That night was the last time Miranda saw her friend alive. The last time Rob could sit in a car — or any confined space — without having a panic attack.
>
> The first time Miranda realized she could see ghosts